# Calling function in unmanaged injected dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, createremotethread

I've been trying to solve this problem for days and I still can't get it to work.
I have successfully injected a unmanaged dll into a remote process. There is a function called testfunction inside of the dll which I'm trying to call through CreateRemoteThread.

I have the address (0x6B610000) for the injected dll within the process and the offset to the function (0x70802) which means the function in the dll is at (0x6B680802).

I have exported the function in the dll as well:

```
LIBRARY test
EXPORTS
testfunction
```

This is how I'm trying to call the function:

```
    public uint CallFunction()
    {
        IntPtr _functionPtr = IntPtr.Add(this.modulePtr, 0x70802); //this.modulePtr = 0x6B610000
        uint threadID;
        IntPtr hThread = CreateRemoteThread(this.processHandle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, _functionPtr, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out threadID);
        // wait for thread to exit
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 0xFFFFFFFF);

        // get the thread exit code
        uint exitCode = 0;
        GetExitCodeThread(hThread, out exitCode);

        // close thread handle
        CloseHandle(hThread);

        return exitCode;
    }
```

This is my DLL source:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

DWORD WINAPI testfunction(LPVOID *param); //<--- the test function im trying to call
DWORD WINAPI T_HkThread(LPVOID);
void WriteToLog(std::string _message);


void WriteToLog(std::string _message)
{
    std::ofstream out;
     // std::ios::app is the open mode "append" meaning
     // new data will be written to the end of the file.
     out.open("C:/test/log.txt", std::ios::app);

     std::string str = _message + "\n";
     out << str;
}

DWORD WINAPI testfunction(LPVOID *param)
{
    WriteToLog("YES YOU CALLED THE FUNCTION");
    return 0;
}


DWORD WINAPI T_HkThread(LPVOID)
{
    //Loading CLR INTO PROCESS
    WriteToLog("Thread created...");
    return 0;
} 

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            {
                WriteToLog("Injection done: Creating Thread...");
                CreateThread( NULL, NULL, T_HkThread, NULL, NULL, NULL );
            }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            {

            }
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            {

            }
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
        }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The remote application (winamp) in this example loads the dll (i can see the same address in process hacker) but instantly crashes when I try to call the function "testfunction" inside the dll.

```
winamp caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005) in module winamp.exe at 0023:64bc0802.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any injection here. You don't appear to make any effort to get the other process to load the DLL. Usually you pass the address of `LoadLibrary` to `CreateRemoteThread` and allocate a pointer to a string containing the path of the library as the parameter that is passed to `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: I didn't post the injection since it wasn't needed. I can see in the log.txt that the injection worked. I can see the dll being injected at 0x51FF0000 both by code and in process hacker which means the methods of injection is correct. 0x51FF0000 is the address i got when using LoadLibrary = this.modulePtr

Comment: `_functionPtr` has to be a thread func. That is receives `LPVOID`, returns `DWORD`, and is `__stdcall`.

Comment: You should double check your calculations as to where the function is. Log its address from inside the DLL in the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` code.

Comment: Implement proper error handling so you *know* what is going wrong.  When CreateRemoteThread returns IntPtr.Zero, you'll have to call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() to obtain the winapi error code.  Or directly throw Win32Exception, the better way since it is hard to ignore :)  Big problems in this code are not actually injecting the DLL, not having sufficient access rights on the process handle, not having a guarantee that the DLL actually gets loaded at the intended address.

Comment: Using GetLastWin32Error throws 126 now. Trying to find out what the problem is. I also changed the function to: DWORD __stdcall testfunction(LPVOID *param); Still now working though

Comment: Updated the thread if you guys would care to take another look

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling function in injected DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057687/calling-function-in-injected-dll). It looks like they got the crash, too.

Comment: Been reading the thread but im injecting a 32bit lib into a 32bit process, dont understand why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Well its a good idea not to close the ProcessHandle in the previous function if you are going to use it for later :)

Also adding 0x69772 instead of 69772 wasn't a good idea. The function gets called now without errors.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question you asked. It's a tale about mistakes made in your code that we cannot see. The lesson you should learn is the power of the SSCCE. Had you made one the problem would have been obvious.